# Firebase Google sign in stopped working on iOS 16

Tags: ios, reactjs, firebase, google-signin

I'm working in a React web app project that's using Firebase Google sign in. The sign in apparently stopped working on iOS mobile devices after an update to iOS 16 or higher. The issue is the same in both Safari and Chrome browsers. It still works fine on other devices though. It seems that the page gets reloaded after I have selected my Google account from the list. I've tried inspecting the network tab but I'm not getting any errors.

We're using Firebase version 7.6.2 and I tried updating to the latest, which is 9.15.0 but the problem persists. We also have email + password login and that works just fine on all devices.

Here's the Firebase part of our current code if that helps:

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app'
import 'firebase/auth'
import * as firebaseui from 'firebaseui'
import { apiGET, api } from './api'

const initFirebase = apiGET('/firebase-config-url')
  .then((config) => firebase.initializeApp(config))
  .then(() => firebase.auth())

export const firebaseAuth = initFirebase

export const signInOptions = {
  signInSuccessUrl: '/',
  signInOptions: [
    {
      provider: firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
      customParameters: {
        prompt: 'select_account',
      },
    },
    firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
  ],
}

export const bindUI = (el, options = signInOptions) => {
  firebaseAuth.then((auth) => {
    const ui = new firebaseui.auth.AuthUI(auth)
    ui.start(el, { ...signInOptions, ...options })
  })
}
```

Has anyone else experienced similar issues on newer iOS versions and is there a solution for fixing this?

Comment: I'm working on angular project and I encountered the same issue.
When using iOS 16 or using safari on mac I'm unable to sign in (the user is returned as null) bun on mac it I use chrome for example it works as expected

Comment: I found a workaround here: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/6716 It was some issue in FirebaseUI. Instead of redirect I had to use popup in the sign in flow. But for me the issue was present in all browsers on ios devices, so I'm guessing your issue is different.

Comment: I still havre this with 9.15.0

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments the popup option fixed the issue with IOS 16 and higher and safari for desktops as well in my case. However, if the first request does not work the second one will do (based on my case and testing it in a physical Iphone device). I hope this help anyone. Library: React.js

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).